# Is flat connection holomorphic?

Tags: complex-geometry, connections, holomorphic-bundles

Let $M$ be a complex manifold and $E\to M$ be a holomorphic vector bundle. Let $\nabla:E\to E\otimes A_M^1$ be a **flat** connection, where $A_M^1$ stands for the sheaf/complex vector bundle of smooth 1-forms. If $\nabla$ compatible with the holomorphic structure, i.e., $\nabla^{0,1}=\bar{\partial}^E$, then is $\nabla$ a holomorphic connection (i.e., $\nabla:E\to E\otimes \Omega_M^1$, where $\Omega_M^1$ stands for the sheaf/holomorphic vector bundle of holomorphic 1-forms)?

Without flatness, the two notions are different, cf. p.179 of *Complex Geometry An Introduction* by Daniel Huybrechts.

As I see it, by smooth Riemann-Hilbert correspondence (Thm. C.4.3 of *Period Mappings and Period Domains*), $L:=\ker(\nabla)$ is a local system with $L\otimes_{\mathbb{C}}C_M^{\infty}=E$ as a complex vector bundle and $\nabla=Id_L\otimes d$. Then $\ker(\nabla)\otimes_{\mathbb{C}}O_M$ gives a holomorphic structure on $E$ with respect to which $\nabla$ is a holomorphic connection. But I am not sure if this new  holomorphic structure coincides with the original one on $E$.

Another try: take a local holomorphic frame $\{e_1,\dots,e_r\}$ of $E$, and denote the local connection matrix smooth 1-form by $\Omega$. As $\nabla^{0,1}=\bar{\partial}^E$, then $\Omega^{0,1}=0$. By flatness, $d\Omega+\Omega\wedge \Omega=0$. Consider the $(1,1)$ part of it, we get $\bar{\partial}\Omega=0$, i.e., $\Omega$ is a holomorphic form. This shows that $\nabla$ is holomorphic.

Answer (score 1):

I guess the answer comes a little late, but anyway. For a reference, see  the notes on Nonabelian Hodge Theory by Alberto García-Raboso and Steven Rayan.

Let me clear up the setting: Let $M$ be a complex manifold with sheaf of complex valued smooth $k$-forms $\mathcal{A}^k_M$. Let $\mathcal{O}_M$ be the sheaf of holomorphic functions and $\Omega_M^k = \ker (\bar{\partial} \colon \mathcal{A}^k_M \to \mathcal{A}^{k+1}_M)$ the sheaf of holomorphic $k$-forms.

The answer to your question is basically: yes. Let me explain.

Now, let $(E \to M,\nabla)$ be a flat complex vector bundle (i.e. $\nabla \colon E \to \mathcal{A}^1_M \otimes E$ which satisfies Leibniz rule). Then we can use the splitting into $(1,0)$ and $(0,1)$ part to write $\nabla = \partial_E + \bar{\partial}_E$ and flatness of $\nabla$ implies
$$ \partial_E^2 = 0 \,, \quad \bar{\partial}_E^2 = 0 \,, \quad \partial_E \bar{\partial}_E + \bar{\partial}_E \partial_E = 0 \,.$$
Therefore, $\bar{\partial}_E$ is a Dolbeault operator that turns $E$ into a holomorphic vector bundle $\mathcal{E}$. Furthermore, on this bundle the operator $\partial_E \colon \mathcal{E} \to \Omega^1_M \otimes \mathcal{E}$ satisfies $\partial_E^2 = 0$, i.e. it is flat. This is precisely a flat holomorphic connection.

Remark: I would not call $\nabla$ a holomorphic connection, because it is defined for the smooth sections. Rather $\partial_E$ is the holomorphic connection. (Of course, both agree when acting on holomorphic sections.)

Remark: This also works using the Riemann Hilbert problem. Let $\mathcal{L}$ be a local system of $\mathbb{C}$-vector spaces. Then $(E := \mathcal{L} \otimes_{\mathbb{C}} \mathcal{A}^0_M, \nabla := \mathrm{id} \otimes \mathrm{d})$ is a flat complex vector bundle and $(\mathcal{E} := \mathcal{L} \otimes_{\mathbb{C}} \mathcal{O}_M, \partial_E := \mathrm{id} \otimes \partial)$ is a holomorphic vector bundle with a flat holomorphic connection. The discussion above explains how to go from one to the other.